# Aligning two divs side by side center to page using percentage width

Tags: html, css

Please refer below code

```
<div id="root">
<div id="child1">xxxx</div>
<div id="child2">yyyy</div>
</div>
```

css :

```
#root
{
    width:100%
    margin:0 auto;
}
#root div
{
    width: 50%;
    float:left; 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/33Fzu/133/

i knew we can use"pixel" to align the div center to the page. but i want to do it through percentage width concept.

how can i align the div through percentage width concept that needs to be work in IE8,IE9 and chorme browser in all kind of resolutions.

if i set root width is 80% or 90% then for particular resolution machine the div's are centered but other resolutions its not working.

how can i set width in percentage to align the div in center for all kind of resolutions

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `box-sizing` to `border-box` to include the border inside the element's width:

```css
#root div {
    ...
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**.](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/33Fzu/136)

The `-moz-`-prefixed version is for Firefox, as Firefox does not support the default `box-sizing` property. This does work on IE8, however.

Comment: i can't get you from your answer. i want the div content to be center using percentage width but your answer is related to border. ?

Comment: am not using any border for div just for u guys understanding purpose only i put border color in fiddle

Comment: see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/33Fzu/146/ div content is center to page that's what my question

Answer (score 2):

Try this fiddle link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/neharikapadala/33Fzu/155/

```
#root
{
    width:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-left:20%;
    padding-right:20%;
}

#child1
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:red

}
#child2
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:green
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but please read my question clearly i need to support in all resolutions. it will not align the content to center in other resolutions.

Comment: It will work correctly in all resolutions. I have checked the code in mobile too. Its working as expected.Since we have defined everything in percentage. it will opt the width as per the resolution

Comment: Yah this works perfectly in all resolutions no doubt ... Thank you very much Neharika :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as follows:

The CSS can be like this:

```
#root
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#child1
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;

}
#child2
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: i need to center the div content side by side center to page. your fiddle output is different

Comment: your fiddle output is same what i was getting now. i need "XXXX" and"YYYY" to be in center to page

Comment: add the css that I have added above. YOu will get the output. remove your css and add the new CSS

Comment: i already added your css but not center the div content. you sent same CSS what i used already

Comment: OMG!!! in your fiddle where is the content is center ?"XXX" is till left corner only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48250/discussion-between-sivarajini-and-neharika)